# big size image uploading and reading problem in android?

Tags: android

any one guide me if i am uploading an image from android phone pro grammatically
my application works fine for small images but in case of if my camera is of 3 or 5 mega pixel it takes

big size images for example 2mb which takes too much time to upload and sometimes gives me out of memory exception.

any one suggest me how can i reduce image size so that quality of image is not disturb
or any other suggestion to solve this issue?

```
public class HttpRequest {


    public static HttpData post(String sUrl, Hashtable<String, String> params, ArrayList<File> files,Context mycontext,String path) {
        HttpData ret = new HttpData();
        try {
                String boundary = "*****************************************";
                String newLine = "\r\n";
                int bytesAvailable;
                int bufferSize;
                int maxBufferSize = 4096;
                int bytesRead;

                URL url = new URL(sUrl);


                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setUseCaches(false);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

                //dos.writeChars(params);

                //upload files
                for (int i=0; i<files.size(); i++) {
                        Log.i("HREQ", i+"");
                        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files.get(i));
                        InputStream fis=mycontext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(path));
                        dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + newLine);
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=myfile;filename="
                        + "test.png"  + newLine + newLine);
                        bytesAvailable = fis.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        while (bytesRead > 0) {
                                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                bytesAvailable = fis.available();
                                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                                bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        }
                        dos.writeBytes(newLine);
                        dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--" + newLine);
                        fis.close();
                }
                // Now write the data

                Enumeration keys = params.keys();
                String key, val;
                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                        key = keys.nextElement().toString();
                        val = params.get(key);
                        dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + newLine);
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name="
                        + key + newLine + newLine + val);
                        dos.writeBytes(newLine);
                        dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--" + newLine);

                }
                dos.flush();

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        ret.content += line + "\r\n";
                }

                /*
                //get headers
                Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
                Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> hKeys = headers.entrySet();
                for (Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> i = hKeys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                        Entry<String, List<String>> m = i.next();

                        Log.w("HEADER_KEY", m.getKey() + "");
                        ret.headers.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue().toString());
                        if (m.getKey().equals("set-cookie"))
                        ret.cookies.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue().toString());
                }
                */
                dos.close();
                rd.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
         String value = me.getMessage();
         String val = value;

        } catch (IOException ie) {
         Log.e("here ", "Exception: "+ie.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("HREQ", "Exception: "+e.toString());
        }
        return ret;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where and how you uploading image?

Comment: uploading image from gallery using http post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to bitmap but it lowers the quality of the image.